# How to pass data from a cshtml view to a Vue.js app then into a Vue component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, razor

Being new to Vue.js, I'm trying to pass data from a cshtml view to a Vue app, then from the Vue app to a Vue component within the app and render it there.

I'm trying to pass the data as data attribute within the target div that renders the Vue app:

The rendering div:

```
<div id="schoolsSearch" data-model-value="@Model.Title"></div>
```

Where the Vue app is initiated:

```
new Vue({
        el: '#schoolsSearch',
        data: {
            modelValue: document.getElementById('schoolsSearch').getAttribute('data-model-value').toString()
        },        render: h => h(schoolsSearchApp)
    });
```

Within the Vue app:

```
  data: function () {
            return {
                modelValue: null,
```

The component within the Vue app:

```
<School-Card  v-for="school in limitedItems" :passedvalue="modelValue"  :key="school.DisplayName" :school="school"></School-Card>
```

And within the component:

```
props: ['school'], passedValue: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }

<p>{{ passedValue }}</p>
```

There are no errors, if I view the Vue tools in Firefox I can see modelValue but it's null and hasn't been set to the value passed down from view to app.

What am I missing?

Comment: with a quick glance you didn't declare your props correctly for the component ```School-Card```. it should be something like ```props: { school: String, passedValue: {type: String, required: true,} }``` props property should be either an array or an object

Comment: Thanks, I've updated that.  The value for modelValue is null as well, in the vue app, before it even gets to the component.

Comment: the parent component for ```School-Card``` does it have a value for ```modelValue``` ?
i'm also curious for why using the name ```modelValue``` ?

Comment: No, modelValue is null in the parent vue app. No reason for using that name, it will be changed before going to test anyway.

Comment: move this query ```document.getElementById('schoolsSearch').getAttribute('data-model-value').toString()``` to the parent component and pass it to child component. unless there is a reason why its set when vue app is created

Comment: it would be helpful if you can create a sandbox

Comment: you're last suggestion worked, if you put it as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving the data to the parent component should fix the issue

```js
{
  data: function () {
    return {
      modelValue: document.getElementById('schoolsSearch').getAttribute('data-model-value').toString()
    }
  }
}
```